# How to read a JSON file I wrote to on Heroku?

Tags: node.js, express, heroku

I've created an online quiz program in Express.js. The answers to this quiz are collected in a JSON file contained in the project folder itself.

I deployed this application on Heroku, so that users can solve it. Now the answers will be written on the JSON file bundled with the app. But I have no clue how to look at that JSON file. I don't see any way to look at the file through the Heroku portal. Did I do something wrong? Is there any way?

Answer (score 1):

If you need to read text from a file in server and send it to the client. You need to write a `express.get('/quiz')` route and send the JSON data.

The code should look something like this:

```
const jsonData = require('./quiz.json');
const express = require('express');
const app = express();


app.get('/quiz', (req, res) => {
     res.json(jsonData);
});

app.serve(3000);
```

Comment: thanks enes. But my question is, instead of using any database, my quiz program writes the responses to a json file. And that json file is bundled with deployed application iteself on production. Now how can i see the updated json file?

Answer (score 1):

> The answers to this quiz are collected in a JSON file contained in the project folder itself.

This won't work on Heroku. Its [filesystem is ephemeral](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/dynos#ephemeral-filesystem). You can write to it, but any changes you make will be lost the next time your dyno restarts. This happens frequently ([at least once per day](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/dynos#automatic-dyno-restarts)).

I would recommend using a client-server database instead of a file to store your results. Heroku's own [Postgres service](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/heroku-postgresql) works quite well out of the box. If you prefer other databases you can pick one from [Heroku's list of data store addons](https://elements.heroku.com/addons/#data-stores) or us another cloud database provider.

Finally, if you *really* want to store your data in a JSON file for whatever reason, you'll have to store it elsewhere, e.g. [on Amazon S3](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/s3).